# vgdb: "No such file or directory" shared memory file when running in process network namespace

Tags: gdb, valgrind, gdbserver

I'm trying to debug a program using Valgrind and GDB. To run the program in my test suite it has to be run within a network namespace (using `ip netns exec <namespace>`), as it has to simulate different network connections. To run the program I want to debug I run the following command:

```
ip netns exec my-ns valgrind --leak-check=full --vgdb=yes --vgdb-error=0 <program> <args>
```

This runs without any problems, but when I try to connect using GDB I get the following error:

```
(gdb) target remote | vgdb
Remote debugging using | vgdb
syscall failed: No such file or directory
error opening /tmp/vgdb-pipe-shared-mem-vgdb-<pid>-by-root-on-??? shared memory file
Remote communication error. Target disconnected.: Connection reset by peer.
```

I've tried running the GDB command both within the namespace and without as follows, and they both give me the same error:

```
gdb <binary>
ip netns exec my-ns gdb <binary>
```

When looking at the files generated by VGDB in `/tmp` I find the following:

```
prw------- 1 root root  0 Dec 20 08:31 vgdb-pipe-from-vgdb-to-<pid>-by-root-on-<hostname>
-rw------- 1 root root 48 Dec 20 08:31 vgdb-pipe-shared-mem-vgdb-<pid>-by-root-on-<hostname>
prw------- 1 root root  0 Dec 20 08:31 vgdb-pipe-to-vgdb-from-<pid>-by-root-on-<hostname>
```

I am running all commands as root, so there should be no permissions problems here either. I have also verified that there is no problem running the same process without the process namespace - although then I am unable to perform my tests. Also, curiously enough, when I run without `ip netns exec` I get the following files in `/tmp`, not seeming to pick up my hostname:

```
prw------- 1 root root  0 Dec 20 08:44 'vgdb-pipe-from-vgdb-to-<pid>-by-root-on-???'
-rw------- 1 root root 48 Dec 20 08:44 'vgdb-pipe-shared-mem-vgdb-<pid>-by-root-on-???'
prw------- 1 root root  0 Dec 20 08:44 'vgdb-pipe-to-vgdb-from-<pid>-by-root-on-???'
```

I appreciate your replies.

Comment: What hardware? Which OS? Which version of Valgrind?

Comment: @PaulFloyd The issue has been resolved, but in case others encounter this issue, I'm running on a Debian GNU/Linux machine (bullseye) with valgrind package version 1:3.16.1-1. The shell I'm using is zsh, though the script is written in bash, which may be why the environment variable HOST didn't show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to determine the hostname, Valgrind and vgdb use the following rules

1. Uses the HOST environment variable
2. Uses the HOSTNAME environment variable
3. If neither of the above are set, uses "???"
4. If one of the environment variables was set and the hostname contains '/' then again "???" is used.

I don't know how `ip netns exec` affects such variables. Maybe you can use a script that sets HOSTNAME to whatever Valgrind is seeing and then starts gdb.

Comment: Although the environment variable HOST seemed to be set in my shell, strangely GDB did not pick up on it. I was able to resolve it by simply adding `HOST=<hostname>` manually before my GDB command (even without `ip netns exec`). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, however `???` appeared in a different spot:

```
Remote debugging using | vgdb
syscall failed: No such file or directory
error opening /tmp/vgdb-pipe-shared-mem-vgdb-<pid>-by-???-on-hostname shared memory file
```

On my system, the shared file was actually at `/tmp/vgdb-pipe-shared-mem-vgdb-<pid>-by--on-hostname` (no question marks), I found that by enabling `-v -v` on the valgrind command line invocation.

To fix this, I set `export LOGNAME=""` before the `gdb` invocation and that fixed it.

Originally, I found the fix in https://www.mail-archive.com/valgrind-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg03487.html (apparently vgdb finds the user first via `LOGNAME` then `USER` and I guess none of those were set or were set to an incorrect value)